# Interface Builder not honoring Safe Area alignment constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

In Interface Builder, setting the constraints for a UI element (let's say a button) doesn't change if I make the aligment proportional to the Safe Area or proportional to the Superview.

I have a button which I set its horizontal alignment to be:
[image]

I have another button which I set its horizontal alignment to be:
[image]

Both buttons end up being aligned horizontally:
[image]

I would have expected the button aligned to the Safe Area to be shifted to the right as the Safe Area's leading edge is shifted to the right from the one of the Superview. I'm probably missing something but can't quite understand what is going on here.

The problem is that heights and widths proportional to the Safe Area are honored, so the size of UI elements does change if you make them proportional to the Safe Area or to the Superview. So when you try to layout something with Safe Area proportional heights and widths, and also use Safe Area proportional horizontal and vertical placements, UI Elements don't line up for iPhones with a notch. They kind of lineup for devices like iPads and iPhones with no notch where the Safe Area is very close to the Superview area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things may be causing the confusion...

First, it helps to add a (yellow) view, constrained on all 4 sides to the Safe Area (using iPhone 13 Pro layout):

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the Safe Area has 44-pts **Leading *AND* Trailing**.

So, in Portrait Orientation, both the Superview and the Yellow view have a Width of `390.0` and the CenterX value for both is `195.0`.

When rotated to Landscape, the Superview Width is `844.0` while the Yellow view (constrained to Safe Area) Width is only `756.0` ... that is, 44-pts on each side.

However, the ***CenterX*** value is the same: `422.0`

So, when we constrain a view / label Leading to CenterX of *either* the Superview or Safe Area with a 0.5 Multiplier, the resulting X / Leading value will be `422.0 * 0.5 == 211.0`

Take a look at this example using these constraints:

[image] [image]

- **L1** Leading is `Superview.centerX * 0.5`
- **L2** Leading is `SafeArea.centerX * 0.5`
- **L3** CenterX is `Superview.centerX`
- **L4** Leading is `L3.centerX * 0.5`
- **L5** CenterX is `SafeArea.centerX`
- **L6** Leading is `L5.centerX * 0.5`
- **L7** CenterX is `Superview.centerX` (but Width: 240 instead of 120)
- **L8** Leading is `L7.centerX * 0.5`

As we see, **all** of the "50% of CenterX" labels are aligned.

And, we get the same alignment when rotated:

[image]

Worth noting: If you try to do the same thing with Top and CenterY constraints, you ***WILL*** see an immediate difference... because when rotated to Landscape Orientation, the Safe Area Top and Bottom "padding" are not the same.

Comment: Thanks, @DonMag. To get things to work I created an extra view with the same dimensions as the Safe Area and added the constraints with respect to this view.